# AJAX, caching and timestamps

Tags: ajax, jsp, caching, timestamp

Im getting kind of desperate with a caching issue. Im calling jsp sites via AJAX and I simply wont get the updatet code back but rather an older version.
The same happens when I delete browser cache AND the server cache. 
I read about using timestamps in the url which sounded reasonable. So I added that but the content will simply not update.
Very rarely I get it to work by spamming my code with random out.println commands that print out random strings.
Obviously thats not very efficient.. heh

Any idea what might be the issue? This is serioulsy making me go crazy.

EDIT:

Ok some updates on the situation:
* It seems the browser is not the culprit. Did some testing with Mozilla and IE. It seems there is still some caching happening at the server for some reason.
* Also apparantly its not only happening when doing AJAX request, I just had the same problem on the index.jsp.

I'm not really sure anymore if its of use to post the sources on the AJAX stuff, considering I get the same problem without AJAX. I ll take a look at the server settings again and see if something got messed up in there.

Comment: Show your code. Also, use Firebug to check if the AJAX requests are conditional (check for `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers which indicate that the user agent is trying to leverage its cache, and corresponding 304 or 412 responses from the server. If your AJAX requests are REST, then the user agent is supposed to help you with caching automatically. For example, it should flush a resource from its cache after that resource is successfully `PUT` or `DELETE`d so that when you `GET` it again, it will get it fresh.

Comment: Based on the additional information you provided, I have a sneaking suspicion that there is a proxy server involved, because I find it really unlikely that the web server could be caching results from `index.jsp` and various AJAX requests (unless the application was coded to have such a cache). It might be an transparent proxy, possibly even one introduced by an evil ISP. If so, you could defeat it by using https or possibly by making the web server listen on an unusual port.

Comment: I will talk to our server admin. Unfortunately I cant do that before monday. Thanks for your suggestions so far! I will keep this up-to-date when/if I find out more.